# Ubuntu + Win 7 Dual Boot

Tags: windows, ubuntu, multi-boot

I want to dual boot Ubuntu on my old windows 7 laptop.  Will I ALWAYS need the flash drive I am burning the ISO onto for startup?  Or, once I select "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows", will Ubuntu be on the hard drive and I can re-format the flash drive for other purposes?

Comment: NO, once you installed ubuntu properly alongside with Windows, you can use flash drive for any other purpose.

Answer (score 1):

NO, once you installed ubuntu properly alongside with Windows, you can use flash drive for any other purpose.

Before you do it, please refer [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot) official Ubuntu documentation and more details with GUIs [this](http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/05/install-ubuntu-1404-alongside-windows.html) site.